# Unable to return a variable from a function, when the function is called inside the same function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def m():
    m1 = input()
    m1.lower()
    if m1 in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']:
        return m1
    else:
        m()
f= m()
```

Here, value of f updates as long as if statement is executed, when else is executed which calls the function itself. So, when the second time if is executed(after else) the value of f is not updating and giving out "none"

Comment: You need to return something even when you execute function recursively: `return m()`

Comment: Google "python recursive none" and find at least 20 duplicates. How did you miss those?

Comment: Python strings are immutable. ` m1.lower()` does not modify m1, but returns a new string, which you then ignore.  You need to write `m1 = m1.lower()` to get the result you're expecting.

Answer (score -1):

@Olvin Rought is correct. You need to add `return m()` inside the `else`. If you dont add the return the code will run recursively but will not actually return anything once it enters the else statement

```
def m():
    m1 = input()
    m1.lower()
    if m1 in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']:
        return m1
    else:
        return m()
f= m()
```